# String index out of range: 0 when stored procedure returning empty value in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a created a spring boot app which is calling a Stored procedure to fetch data using CrudRepository. Below is the implementation of Repo interface:

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<EmpEntity, Long> {

@Query(value = "call myStoredProc(:empID, :empProv);", nativeQuery = true)
Map<String, String> findWithNumber(@Param("empID ") String empID, @Param("empProv ") String empProv);
}
```

The stored procedure is returning 10 variables and out of those 1 value is returning blank value. Due to this behavior I am getting following error:

```
2020-06-10 08:02:46.118 ERROR 23724 --- [nio-8050-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0] with root cause
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CharacterTypeDescriptor.wrap(CharacterTypeDescriptor.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CharacterTypeDescriptor.wrap(CharacterTypeDescriptor.java:16) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
```

I can fix the issue by putting NULLIF(a.addressType,"") addressType in stored procedure but I want to understand the reason behind the issue and also the possible fix in Spring boot app.

Comment: I add null checks in my code to avoid StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Check null  and set "" empty string in code it will not be automatic

Comment: Guys I am using CrudRepository implementation so JPA is handling everything by its own. I have not written any custom code.

Comment: Any input on the issue?